# Apache Spark (python): find pairwise distances between 2 RDDs

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, apache-spark, bigdata

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have two RDDs, one is a training set the other a testing set.  I would like to find the pairwise distances between each point in the two sets so that I can perform a knn classifier.  For each element in the testing set, I would like to save to disk an ordered list of the 100 closest training points in ascending order by distance.  For example, given a single testing element I would like to have a list that looks like the following

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ..., 1]
```

where the 0 index element is the closest sample of the one hundred values to the testing set point (the elements themselves are the actual class of the sample).  I then plan to use these lists to optimize for the value of k.  As an additional requirement I would like to also look at different distant metrics.

In the case I have outlined above the training and testing sets were created by sampling my entire dataset.  I would like to use the optimal values that I will find using the above approach to pick the knn parameters to use on all of my data.

Due to the amount of data that I have and my limited amount of memory I cannot use sparks built in cartesian product method to simplify my problem.  What might be the most optimal way to go about this task?

Comment: where you able to find the answer to this question?

Comment: It was quite awhile ago, but if I remember correctly I wasn't able to find an efficient solution.  In my case the problem was the amount of available memory.  I think I just ended up taking very small samples, in several different iterations, and then looking at the results.  Not ideal, and the performance (accuracy) I think was subpar.